# How can I limit the number of images to display based on the screen size of the device on which I try to open my homepage?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a number of images in one row on a one page website.
    I'm using ajax to fetch the images from the folder  and  displaying them but they are getting
    displayed outside the browser viewport (width) in  the next line. **I want to limit the number of

    images to display according   to the device screen size**. How can i do that?

Here is  my jquery code:

```
 $('document').ready(function() {
        var dir = "img/images/"; // folder containing images
         var fileextension = ".jpg";
        $.ajax({
            //This will retrieve the contents of the folder if the folder is configured as 'browsable'
            url: dir,
            success: function (data) {
            //Lsit all png file names in the page
            $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
                //when loading to the server try window.location.host in the below line  

                var filename = this.href.replace(window.location, "").replace("http:///", "");
                $("#images-part").append($("<img src=" + dir + filename + " alt='friend1' class='img-circle dabbers' ></img>"));
            });
         }
        });
    });
```

Here is my div in which i am displaying the images.

```
<div class="col-md-12  hidden-sm hidden-xs image-space " id="images-part">
    <img src="img/add_user.png" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " >
    <!--<img src="img/images/images%20(1).jpg" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " >
    <img src="img/images/images%20(2).jpg" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " >
    <img src="img/images/images%20(3).jpg" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " >
    <img src="img/images/images%20(4).jpg" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " >
    <img src="img/images/download.jpg" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " >
    <img src="img/images/images%20(5).jpg" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " >
    <img src="img/images/images%20(6).jpg" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " >
    <img src="img/images/images%20(9).jpg" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " >-->

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly if you are using bootstrap, then you can add images to the grid rather than adding them to the div straighaway:**

Example :-

```
<div class="col-md-12  hidden-sm hidden-xs image-space " id="images-part">

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><img src="img/add_user.png" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " ></div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><img src="img/images/images%20(2).jpg" alt="friend1" class="img-circle " ></div>
.
.
.
. 


                </div>
```

**Secondly if you still want to control the number of images based on device width, then you can check the window width and plan the number of images accordingly and then call only that number of images through ajax or display only that number in ajax callback**

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();

var numImages = windowWidth > 500 ? 5 : windowWidth > 400 ? 4 : 3;
```

// You can set the numbers as you need and then use this number for further use.

Comment: Thank you abhinsit , i got the logic , i will try it out,

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Calculate the width of every image appended together and check if its larger than the screen and if so, hide the next image.

```
    var imgWidth = 0;

    $(data).find("a:contains(" + fileextension + ")").each(function () {
        var visibility = "visible";
        if(imgWidth > $(window).width()){

          visibility = "hidden";         

        }

        var filename = this.href.replace(window.location,"").replace("http:///", "");
        var image = $("<img src=" + dir + filename + " alt='friend1' class='img-circle dabbers' ></img>")

        image.css("visibility", visibility);

        $("#images-part").append(image);

        imgWidth = imgWidth + image.width();

    });

 }

});
```

and then do the same with a resize event. Like this:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {

var imgWidth = 0;

$(".img-circle").each(function () {
    var image = $(this);
    var visibility = "visible";
    if(imgWidth > $(window).width()){

      visibility = "hidden";         

    }
    image.css("visibility", visibility);

    imgWidth = imgWidth + image.width();

});

   });
```

Comment: Thank you jake for you answer, but the size of the image is not increasing but the images displayed at the end of the row are shifting to the next line thats why i want to limit the number of images to display according to the screen size,  Again thank you for your reply.

Comment: Okay, check out abhinsit answer and see if it works for you!